# python can't find libraries if run from incron

Tags: python, centos, anaconda, incron, abrt

I have a python script that processes excel files. I this script is run via python from the command line, it runs as expected but when I run from incron, it does't appear to see my imports, such as pandas

this is how I call from incron:

```
file/to/monitor IN_CREATE,IN_MOVED_TO /usr/bin/sh /my/main/shell/script
```

this is how my script looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
source activate my_env
python /absolute/path/to/python/script
```

and now as I check on the logs, from abrt,

**step1.1_executeConsolidation.py:2::ImportError: No module named pandas**

I'm thinking this is just an environment issue with incron, but I'm not sure how to set it up properly.

I use anaconda by the way. If run manually, I don't have any library dependency issues

Comment: I'd suggest `set -ex` at the top of your shell script, it'll likely help you find your error

Comment: thanks another tool I can use :) I tried running my shell script that runs the python script, it works fine. now, I tried running the shell script from incron, now it doesn't work

Comment: There should be more output that tells you what went wrong now, can you produce the entire output (and whatever log files `incron` provides)?

Comment: for future readers. for now I have given up on incron, and will fallback to cron which works perfectly to how I want it to proceed. If I have more time, then I will dig deeper with incron.